# Converting Latex String to Java String

Tags: java, android, latex

How can i convert a latex string to a java string.
Like i have a latex

### \frac { 4 x } { \sqrt { x ^ { 2 } + 1 }}##

i want this to be converted to java string like (4x)/sqrt(x^2+1)

Comment: Hi Abid, what have you tried?

Comment: @ZUNJAE, i have tried many available libraries but none of them is working.

Comment: @ZUNJAE found this one https://github.com/Crownie/latex-to-js but it is throwing error.

Comment: That's a javascript library. Also, what erorr are you getting?

Comment: it gives syntax error on its own examples

Comment: Why are you using a JavaScript library?

Comment: i didn't find anything in java so i thought that javascript library will do the job

Comment: How are you gonna get the JavaScript library in Android Studio?

Comment: i placed the library in assets folder and loaded that to webview

Comment: Loading WebView with a custom JavaScript _just_ to convert a simple Latex code to a Java String. I'm sorry but I can not help you.

Comment: may this can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/tex-rendering-in-a-java-application